# Facebook notification

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Anyone know how to post a notification for a user when my application makes a post in their wall? I looked through the documentation but no info there. I'm using the php sdk.

Comment: isn't clear what are you asking - about user app notification or about how to post with a user wall?

Answer (score 1):

You can't really control notifications anymore.

The user will (probably) receive a notification if you send him a request using the new Requests 2.0 protocol, easily done using the Request Dialog.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

Comment: i see, i just want to make a post on a user's wall, not send him a request to my application.

Comment: your question isn't really clear.  what are you trying to do, cause a notification (the red globe thing on the top of the screen) or write to a certain user's wall?